# Issues with kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 and scala 2.11.7

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

For the past 6 months,I am the dev for our solution written on top of kafka-0.8.1.1. It is in stable for us. We thought we would upgrade to kafka-0.9.0.1.
With the server upgrade, we did not face any issues.

We have our own solution built to extract the messages and write to different destinations and also messages read by storm. For our unit tests we were using the following maven artifact

```
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
<version>0.8.1.1</version>
```

I could not find, 0.9.0.1 version for kafka_2.9.2. Hence I moved to kafka_2.11 first. This is the artifact used:

```
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0.1</version>
```

I was running into following issue:

```
scala.ScalaObject not found issue
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
kafkaConfig<init> issue with NoSuchMethodError (Ljava/util/map;)Ljava/util/map
```

Also most of the time, I would run into KafkaServerStartable(both in kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1 and kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1) hang issue. But with the same unit tests, I never got into kafka server hang issue with kafka_2.9.2.

Could you please help me with my problem ?
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Check you classpath to see if any 2.10 version of scala library exists. This might be caused by a version conflict.

Comment: *When* and *where* are you running into the "ScalaObject not found issue"?  In your custom application, in Storm / Storm's Kafka spout, ...?

Comment: When I am running storm kafka spout tests, it starts kafka server for unit test using KafkaServerStartable. With the below configs, it tries to start and runs into KafkaConfig error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. following up on my question: 
This is the kafka config that the existing code is using to start the test server:
dependency that I tried:

`<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId> # in this, scala 11.4, 11.7 used alternativel to verify
<version>0.9.0.1</version>`

`<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId> # in this scala 10.4 is used
<version>0.9.0.1</version>`

public KafkaTestServer(int port, ZookeeperTestServer zkServer, String brokerId, int defaultPartitionCount) throws Exception {
        this.zkServer = zkServer;

```
    KafkaConfig config = getKafkaConfig(zkServer.getConnectString(), port, brokerId, defaultPartitionCount);
    kafkaServer = new KafkaServerStartable(config);

    kafkaServer.startup();
    ProducerConfig conf = new ProducerConfig(getProducerConfig(getKafkaBrokerString()));
    producer = new Producer<>(conf);

}

private KafkaConfig getKafkaConfig(String zkConnectString, int port, String brokerId, int defaultPartitionCount) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", zkConnectString);
    props.setProperty("broker.id", brokerId);
    props.setProperty("port", Integer.toString(port));
    createKafkaDataDirectory();
    props.setProperty("log.dirs", dataDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    props.setProperty("num.partitions", Integer.toString(defaultPartitionCount));
    props.setProperty("retry.backoff.ms", "500");

    return new KafkaConfig(props, false);
}
```